# Make sidebar to be beside dashboard content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Goal:
Make sidebar class to be beside of dashboard.

Problem:
The Sidebar is over dashboard and not beside of the dashboard content.
What class should be instead of 'col-sm-2'? ()

jsbin:
https://jsbin.com/xenuwuvisu/edit?html,output

Thank you!

```css
/*
 * Global add-ons
 */

.sub-header {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

/*
 * Top navigation
 * Hide default border to remove 1px line.
 */
.navbar-fixed-top {
  border: 0;
}

/*
 * Sidebar
 */

/* Hide for mobile, show later */
.sidebar {
  display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
  }
}

/* Sidebar navigation */
.nav-sidebar {
  margin-right: -21px; /* 20px padding + 1px border */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.nav-sidebar > li > a {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.nav-sidebar > .active > a,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:hover,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #428bca;
}


/*
 * Main content
 */

.main {
  padding: 20px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .main {
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
}
.main .page-header {
  margin-top: 0;
}


/*
 * Placeholder dashboard ideas
 */

.placeholders {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.placeholders h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.placeholder {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.placeholder img {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0053)https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/ -->
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Dashboard Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>





  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="active"><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/#">Reports</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/#">Analytics</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/#">Export</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/">Nav item</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/">Nav item again</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/">One more nav</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/">Another nav item</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/">More navigation</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/">Nav item again</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/">One more nav</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/">Another nav item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
          <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>

          <div class="row placeholders">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="200" height="200" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Label</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="200" height="200" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Label</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="200" height="200" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Label</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
              <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="200" height="200" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
              <h4>Label</h4>
              <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <h2 class="sub-header">Section title</h2>
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                  <th>Header</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,001</td>
                  <td>Lorem</td>
                  <td>ipsum</td>
                  <td>dolor</td>
                  <td>sit</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,002</td>
                  <td>amet</td>
                  <td>consectetur</td>
                  <td>adipiscing</td>
                  <td>elit</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,003</td>
                  <td>Integer</td>
                  <td>nec</td>
                  <td>odio</td>
                  <td>Praesent</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,003</td>
                  <td>libero</td>
                  <td>Sed</td>
                  <td>cursus</td>
                  <td>ante</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,004</td>
                  <td>dapibus</td>
                  <td>diam</td>
                  <td>Sed</td>
                  <td>nisi</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,005</td>
                  <td>Nulla</td>
                  <td>quis</td>
                  <td>sem</td>
                  <td>at</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,006</td>
                  <td>nibh</td>
                  <td>elementum</td>
                  <td>imperdiet</td>
                  <td>Duis</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,007</td>
                  <td>sagittis</td>
                  <td>ipsum</td>
                  <td>Praesent</td>
                  <td>mauris</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,008</td>
                  <td>Fusce</td>
                  <td>nec</td>
                  <td>tellus</td>
                  <td>sed</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,009</td>
                  <td>augue</td>
                  <td>semper</td>
                  <td>porta</td>
                  <td>Mauris</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,014</td>
                  <td>per</td>
                  <td>inceptos</td>
                  <td>himenaeos</td>
                  <td>Curabitur</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>1,015</td>
                  <td>sodales</td>
                  <td>ligula</td>
                  <td>in</td>
                  <td>libero</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The sidebar has `position:fixed` set. So that `col-2` is ' half useless ' meaning that it has the width of a `col-2` but that width is not taken into consideration when it comes to occupied space. That width is ignored by the other elements.

You are already trying to add `offset` but the className you use is incorrect . You need to add that  `offset left` to the content equal to the `sidebar` width but  the syntax should be `offset-breakpoint-numberOfCols` so instead of `col-md-offset-2`  you should use `offset-md-2`

See bellow the solution with offset ( example ) or [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/wezulivuru/1/edit?html,output)

```css
.sub-header {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}


.navbar-fixed-top {
  border: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  display: none;
}

.nav-sidebar {
  margin-right: -21px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

.nav-sidebar>li>a {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.nav-sidebar>.active>a,
.nav-sidebar>.active>a:hover,
.nav-sidebar>.active>a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #428bca;
}




.main {
  padding: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .main {
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
}

.main .page-header {
  margin-top: 0;
}


/*
 * Placeholder dashboard ideas
 */

.placeholders {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.placeholders h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.placeholder {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.placeholder img {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed!important;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="active"><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/#">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/#">Analytics</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/#">Export</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/">Nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/">Nav item again</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/">One more nav</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/">Another nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/">More navigation</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/">Nav item again</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/">One more nav</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/dashboard/">Another nav item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2 main">
      <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>

      <div class="row placeholders">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
          <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="200" height="200" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
          <h4>Label</h4>
          <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
          <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="200" height="200" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
          <h4>Label</h4>
          <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
          <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="200" height="200" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
          <h4>Label</h4>
          <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 placeholder">
          <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAHd3dwAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" width="200" height="200" class="img-responsive" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
          <h4>Label</h4>
          <span class="text-muted">Something else</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h2 class="sub-header">Section title</h2>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>1,001</td>
              <td>Lorem</td>
              <td>ipsum</td>
              <td>dolor</td>
              <td>sit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,002</td>
              <td>amet</td>
              <td>consectetur</td>
              <td>adipiscing</td>
              <td>elit</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,003</td>
              <td>Integer</td>
              <td>nec</td>
              <td>odio</td>
              <td>Praesent</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,003</td>
              <td>libero</td>
              <td>Sed</td>
              <td>cursus</td>
              <td>ante</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,004</td>
              <td>dapibus</td>
              <td>diam</td>
              <td>Sed</td>
              <td>nisi</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,005</td>
              <td>Nulla</td>
              <td>quis</td>
              <td>sem</td>
              <td>at</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,006</td>
              <td>nibh</td>
              <td>elementum</td>
              <td>imperdiet</td>
              <td>Duis</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,007</td>
              <td>sagittis</td>
              <td>ipsum</td>
              <td>Praesent</td>
              <td>mauris</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,008</td>
              <td>Fusce</td>
              <td>nec</td>
              <td>tellus</td>
              <td>sed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,009</td>
              <td>augue</td>
              <td>semper</td>
              <td>porta</td>
              <td>Mauris</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,014</td>
              <td>per</td>
              <td>inceptos</td>
              <td>himenaeos</td>
              <td>Curabitur</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>1,015</td>
              <td>sodales</td>
              <td>ligula</td>
              <td>in</td>
              <td>libero</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
remove that position fixed from the sidebar
```

or give width to the sidebar with position fixed and give that width as padding-left to the dashboard (and remove row and col-sm-2 and col-sm-9)